# Deriving the moment generating function of the negative binomial .

Tags: statistics

\begin{align}M_x\left(t \right)&=\sum_{x=k}^\infty{\binom{x-1}{k-1}}p^kq^{x-k}e^{tx}\\&  = (e^tp)^k\sum_{x=0}^\infty\binom{k-1+x}{k-1}(e^tq)^x\end{align}

How do we get $\sum_{x=0}^\infty\binom{k-1+x}{k-1}(e^tq)^x = (1+qe^t)^{-k} ?$

Comment: A google search gives these links: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848449/deriving-moment-generating-function-of-the-negative-binomial, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2830021/mgf-of-the-negative-binomial-distribution,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2180501/moment-generating-function-negative-binomial-alternative-formula.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I did that. It didn't help much.